# Convert json-lines to tsv, producing a separate line for each array item

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I have the following input file

```
["alice", ["foo", "bar", "baz"]]
["bob", ["qux", "quux"]]
⋮
```

and I want to convert it to a tab separated file that looks like the following (note the lack of quotes)

```
alice   foo
alice   bar
alice   baz
bob     qux
bob     quux
⋮
```

All the array elements are guaranteed to be strings (no nulls).
Can you help me come up with a jq script to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `last` item (or equally the `.[1]` item) with each of its own items (`.[]`), then turn all of it into tab-separated values using `@tsv`:

```bash
jq -r 'last = last[] | @tsv' input.json
```

```
alice   foo
alice   bar
alice   baz
bob qux
bob quux
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OKU1ZcNn29V)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it by placing the first element in an array and then using the built-in [`combinations`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#combinations,combinations(n)).

```bash
jq --raw-output '.[0]=[.[0]] | combinations | @tsv' input.json
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/0jRNnm3RdVH).